# Can I integrate with scipy's odeint until a local max is found?

Tags: python, scipy, ode, odeint

This is my first question on here, so please go easy on me. I'm wondering if there is a way to integrate an ODE system only until a local max of a specified variable is found. Here is some more detail:

Let's call our ODE system `dX/dt = F(X) where X(t) = [x1(t), x2(t), ... , xn(t)]`. Assume the solution to this system is attracted to a stable limit cycle C everywhere but at one unstable fixed point p. Choose some initial conditions X0 not p, and not in C. We wish to follow the trajectory of the solution to:

```
dX/dt = F(X), X(0) = X0    (*)
```

just until x1(t) reaches its first local max.

Progress:
Using scipy.integrate.odeint I am able to find the solution of the limit cycle C and its period T, but starting at an arbitrary point the only way I've been able to solve this problem is by solving (*) for a 'long time' (maybe 4*T) and, assuming this is a long enough time, determine the first local max of x1 after the fact. My larger project requires this to be done many times, so I'm trying to reduce computation time wherever I can. It seems like there has to be a faster way to do this without writing my own ode solver.

It's possible (and likely) that I'm making this too complicated? If you think of a different way to do this I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The sundials suite (acessible via e.g Assimulo) has root finding capabilities within their solvers CVODE and IDA.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but the following code should work or at least help:

```
from scipy.integrate import ode

y0, t0 = [1.0j, 2.0], 0

def f(t, y, arg1):
    return [1j*arg1*y[0] + y[1], -arg1*y[1]**2]

r = ode(f).set_integrator('zvode', method='bdf')
r.set_initial_value(y0, t0).set_f_params(2.0)
t1 = 10
dt = 1

older = 0
previous = 0
current = 0
while r.successful() and not (older <  previous and prevous > current):
    older = previous
    previous = current
    current = r.integrate(r.t+dt)

print("Maximum occurs at {}".format(r.t - dt))
```

I would also further look into [python ode](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html)

EDIT:

even better would be to use the `solout` which can be found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.set_solout.html#scipy.integrate.ode.set_solout)

Comment: If you're posting as an answer, you may want to take the time to make sure the answer is tested. Typically untested code is dangerous code.