# Finding equilibria of ODE as a function of initial conditions

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode

Let us assume I have an ODE with x'(t) = f(x) with the respective solution x(t) = ϕ(x(0),t) of a initial condition x(0). Now I intend to calculate numerically the equilibria as a function of their initial condition: eq(x0) := ϕ(x0, ∞). The ODEs are such that these equilibria exist unambiguously for all initial conditions (including eq = ∞).

My poor man's approach would be to integrate the ODE up to a late time and fetch that value (for brevity I do not show the plotting):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# ODE
def func(X,t):
    return [ X[2]**2 * (X[0] - X[1]),
             X[2]**3 * (X[0] + 3 * X[1]),
             -X[2]**2] 

# Forming a grid
n = 15
x0 = x1 = np.linspace(0,1,n)
x0_,x1_ = np.meshgrid(x0,x1)
eq = np.zeros([n,n,3])

t  = np.linspace(0,100,1000)  
x2 = 1

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        X = odeint(func,[x0_[j,i],x1_[j,i],x2], t)
        eq[j,i,:] = X[-1,:]
```

Naive example above:

[image]

The problem with that approach is that you can never be sure if it converged. I know that you can just find the roots of f(x), but this would not yield the equilibria as a function of their initial conditions (You could trace them back, but since this function is not injective, you will not find values for all initial values). I somehow need a ODE solver which integrates until an equilibria is reached (or stops integrating if it goes beyond a limit). Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I consider this question off-topic here as it is asking for algorithmic approaches and has nothing to do with programming. It is probably best suited for [scicomp.se].

Comment: Acutally I am searching for an alternative to scipy.odeint since in this scenario it is not possible to introduce a stop-condition for the integration. I would consider this to be a programming-related question

Comment: I thought your problem was to find some criterion for stopping the integration in the first place. If you already have that the criterion, you can strongly boil down your question.

Comment: From question [Can I integrate with scipy's odeint until a local max is found?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30597976/5358968), it looks like you can call `integrate` to a time, test, then integrate further. From [Does scipy.integrate.ode.set_solout work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26738676/5358968), it looks like you can provide a stopping condition with `set_solout`. I didn't get much value from looking for zeroes since I got muddled with the `x_2` term in `f_1`.